# Get all host names associated with the IP

Tags: python-3.x

I want to retrieve all the hostnames associated with the IP.

I ran into an error while using **requests** module in python. And the data that the error contains I want that data.

First I got the IP of of youtube.com I wanted to get the webpage using ip address only so using ping I got the IP address of **youtube.com**

IP `172.217.163.78`

Then I made the request

```
import requests
session_ = requests.Session()
res_ = session_.get('https://172.217.163.78')
```

ERROR

```
\Python3.7.2\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='172.217.163.78', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError("hostname '172.217.163.78'
 doesn't match either of '*.google.com', '*.android.com',
 '*.appengine.google.com', '*.cloud.google.com', '*.g.co', '*.gcp.gvt2.com', '*.ggpht.cn', '*.google-analytics.com',
 '*.google.ca', '*.google.cl', '*.google.co.in', 
 '*.google.co.jp', '*.google.co.uk', '*.google.com.ar', 
 '*.google.com.au', '*.google.com.br', '*.google.com.co',
 '*.google.com.mx', '*.google.com.tr', '*.google.com.vn',
 '*.google.de', '*.google.es', '*.google.fr', '*.google.hu',
 '*.google.it', '*.google.nl', '*.google.pl', '*.google.pt',
 '*.googleadapis.com', '*.googleapis.cn', 
 '*.googlecommerce.com', '*.googlevideo.com', '*.gstatic.cn',
 '*.gstatic.com', '*.gstaticcnapps.cn', '*.gvt1.com', 
 '*.gvt2.com', '*.metric.gstatic.com', '*.urchin.com', 
 '*.url.google.com', '*.youtube-nocookie.com', 
 '*.youtube.com', '*.youtubeeducation.com', 
 '*.youtubekids.com', '*.yt.be', '*.ytimg.com', 
 'android.clients.google.com', 'android.com', 
 'developer.android.google.cn', 
 'developers.android.google.cn', 'g.co', 'ggpht.cn', 'goo.gl', 
 'google-analytics.com', 'google.com', 'googlecommerce.com'
 , 'source.android.google.cn', 'urchin.com', 'www.goo.gl',
 'youtu.be', 'youtube.com', 'youtubeeducation.com', 
 'youtubekids.com', 'yt.be'")))
```

Is there a way to get all the above hostnames, and is there a way to solve this problem ***SSLError*** that i'm getting

Comment: Why not just use `res_ = session_.get('https://youtube.com')`?

Comment: I just wanted to know why I am I getting this ERROR. It works fine with **http**.

Comment: If that is all you wanted to know, then you should rewrite the question.  But the error message tells the problem.

Comment: Is there a way to solve it using only IP. And I also want hostnames

Comment: Your question is not well phrased. Please ask a slightly different question. As it stands, you seem to be asking about strcmp() wildcarding in a cert. Clearly you could query "g.co" and test if 172.217.6.46 equals 172.217.163.78. But for a wildcard like "*.google.com", it's not like you'll have enough information to decide you should query "search.google.com" and compare 172.217.6.78 against your target IP. If you're trying to manipulate DNS A, AAAA, & PTR records, then please say so when you ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
import requests
session_ = requests.Session()
res_ = session_.get('https://172.217.163.78', verify=False)
print (res_.url)

#Output
# http://www.google.com
```

Have you concerned using socket instead of request?

```
import socket
from pprint import pprint

ip_address = socket.gethostbyname('www.abc.com')
pprint (socket.gethostbyaddr(ip_address))

sys.exit(0)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
('www.pitchsharktank.com',
['250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa',
'www.disneycampusrep.com',
'www.disneycollateral.com',
'www.disneyinternsinfo.com',
'www.missiontimekeeper.com',
'www.watchdisneyjunior.go.com',
'www.disneycastingscout.com',
'www.disneyimaginations.com',
'www.disneyprogramsblog.com',
'www.disneyvacationclub.disney.go.com',
'www.watchdisneychannel.go.com',
'www.wdwcollegeprogramecard.com',
'www.wdwcollegeprogramecard2.com',
'www.disneyinternationalepresentation.com',
 many many more here],
['199.181.132.250'])
```

**UPDATE**

I spent more than half the day looking into the hostname issue. I have found that this problem is complex, especially for IP addresses assigned to Google.

For example:

```
ping www.youtube.com
PING youtube-ui.l.google.com (64.233.185.93): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 64.233.185.93: icmp_seq=0 ttl=41 time=19.820 ms

#############################################################

nslookup www.youtube.com
www.youtube.com canonical name = youtube-ui.l.google.com.
Name:   youtube-ui.l.google.com
Address: 172.217.11.142
Name:   youtube-ui.l.google.com
Address: 64.233.176.190
Name:   youtube-ui.l.google.com
Address: 64.233.177.91
Name:   youtube-ui.l.google.com
Address: 64.233.177.93
Name:   youtube-ui.l.google.com
Address: 64.233.177.190
Name:   youtube-ui.l.google.com
Address: 64.233.185.91
Name:   youtube-ui.l.google.com
Address: 64.233.185.93
Name:   youtube-ui.l.google.com
Address: 64.233.185.136
Name:   youtube-ui.l.google.com
Address: 64.233.185.190
Name:   youtube-ui.l.google.com
Address: 74.125.138.190
Name:   youtube-ui.l.google.com
Address: 74.125.196.91
Name:   youtube-ui.l.google.com
Address: 108.177.122.91
Name:   youtube-ui.l.google.com
Address: 108.177.122.93
Name:   youtube-ui.l.google.com
Address: 108.177.122.136
Name:   youtube-ui.l.google.com
Address: 108.177.122.190
Name:   youtube-ui.l.google.com
Address: 172.217.0.78

#############################################################

dig www.youtube.com
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.youtube.com.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.youtube.com.    9446    IN  CNAME   youtube-ui.l.google.com.
youtube-ui.l.google.com. 132    IN  A   64.233.185.190
youtube-ui.l.google.com. 132    IN  A   74.125.138.136
youtube-ui.l.google.com. 132    IN  A   74.125.138.190
youtube-ui.l.google.com. 132    IN  A   74.125.196.91
youtube-ui.l.google.com. 132    IN  A   74.125.196.93
youtube-ui.l.google.com. 132    IN  A   172.217.0.78
youtube-ui.l.google.com. 132    IN  A   172.217.0.142
youtube-ui.l.google.com. 132    IN  A   172.217.2.46
youtube-ui.l.google.com. 132    IN  A   172.217.4.14
youtube-ui.l.google.com. 132    IN  A   172.217.164.78
youtube-ui.l.google.com. 132    IN  A   173.194.219.136
youtube-ui.l.google.com. 132    IN  A   173.194.219.190
youtube-ui.l.google.com. 132    IN  A   64.233.177.91
youtube-ui.l.google.com. 132    IN  A   64.233.177.93
youtube-ui.l.google.com. 132    IN  A   64.233.177.136
youtube-ui.l.google.com. 132    IN  A   64.233.177.190
```

The IP address that you provided in your original question doesn't appear in either the ping, nslookup or dig results.

In Apple Safari, Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox the URL https://172.217.163.78 returns https://www.google.com.

The ShowIP extension in Mozilla Firefox shows that the IP address for https://www.youtube.com is 2607:f8b0:4002:c00::88, which is an IPv6 address.

I also found this:

```
       FQDN:  youtube.com
Domain Name:  youtube.com
Name servers: ns1.google.com
              ns2.google.com
              ns3.google.com
              ns4.google.com
IP numbers:   2404:6800:4003:805::200e
              2404:6800:4004:801::200e
              2404:6800:4006:809::200e
              2607:f8b0:4004:802::200e
              2607:f8b0:4005:807::200e
              2607:f8b0:400a:804::200e
              2800:3f0:4001:80a::200e
              2a00:1450:4009:812::200e
              2a00:1450:400b:c01::be
              74.125.193.91
              74.125.193.93
              74.125.193.136
              74.125.193.190
              172.217.7.238
              172.217.24.78
              172.217.30.78
              216.58.195.78
              216.58.197.174
              216.58.203.110
              216.58.206.46
              216.58.217.46
```

**LOOKUP fully qualified domain names:**

```
import socket

##############################################
# IP addresses linked to YouTube on 01-28-2019
##############################################
ip_addresses =['2404:6800:4003:805::200e',
               '2404:6800:4004:801::200e',
               '2404:6800:4006:809::200e',
               '2607:f8b0:4004:802::200e',
               '2607:f8b0:4005:807::200e',
               '2607:f8b0:400a:804::200e',
               '2800:3f0:4001:80a::200e',
               '2a00:1450:4009:812::200e',
               '2a00:1450:400b:c01::be',
               '74.125.193.91',
               '74.125.193.93',
               '74.125.193.136',
               '74.125.193.190',
               '172.217.7.238',
               '172.217.24.78',
               '172.217.30.78',
               '216.58.195.78',
               '216.58.197.174',
               '216.58.203.110',
               '216.58.206.46',
               '216.58.217.46']

for iP_address in ip_addresses:
  fully_qualified_domain_name = socket.getfqdn(str(iP_address))
  print (fully_qualified_domain_name)

# OUTPUT
sin10s06-in-x0e.1e100.net
nrt12s02-in-x0e.1e100.net
syd09s15-in-x0e.1e100.net
iad23s58-in-x0e.1e100.net
sfo07s16-in-x0e.1e100.net
sea15s08-in-x0e.1e100.net
2800:3f0:4001:80a::200e
lhr35s10-in-x0e.1e100.net
2a00:1450:400b:c01::be
ig-in-f91.1e100.net
ig-in-f93.1e100.net
ig-in-f136.1e100.net
ig-in-f190.1e100.net
iad23s58-in-f14.1e100.net
sin10s06-in-f14.1e100.net
gru06s34-in-f14.1e100.net
sfo07s16-in-f78.1e100.net
nrt12s02-in-f14.1e100.net
syd09s15-in-f14.1e100.net
lhr35s10-in-f14.1e100.net
sea15s08-in-f14.1e100.net
```

As you can see, not one of these FQDN equals youtube.com.

I also decided to lookup the IP addresses assigned to YouTube through ARIN. the code below loops through those addresses.

```
import socket
import ipaddress
from dns import reversename, resolver

# IPv4 addresses listed at whois.arin.net for YouTube
# 64.15.112.0/20 = number of hosts 4,096
# 104.237.160.0/19 = number of hosts 8,192
# 208.65.152.0/22 = number of hosts 1,024
# 208.117.224.0/19 = number of hosts 8,192
youtube_IPv4_addresses = ['64.15.112.0/20','104.237.160.0/19', '208.65.152.0/22', '208.117.224.0/19']

# IPv6 addresses listed at whois.arin.net for YouTube
# Start Range: 2620:11a:a000:0:0:0:0:0
# End Range: 2620:11a:a0ff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
# No. of host: 309485009821345068724781056
youtube_IPv6_addresses = ['2620:11A:A000::/40']

#############################################
# This function is designed to query the IPv4
# address blocks assigned to YouTube for their
# corresponding PTR records, which are used
# for the Reverse DNS (Domain Name System)
#############################################
def get_ipv4_hostnames():
  for network in youtube_IPv4_addresses:
    ip_addresses = ipaddress.IPv4Network(network)
    for ip_address in ip_addresses:
      try:
        rev_name = reversename.from_address(str(ip_address))
        reversed_dns = str(resolver.query(rev_name,"PTR")[0])
        print (reversed_dns)
      except Exception as error:
        print ('The following error occurred: \n {}'.format(error))

#############################################
# WARNING  WARNING  WARNING  WARNING  WARNING
#############################################
#  There are 309485009821345068724781056
#  possible hosts within the IPv6 address
#  range assigned to YouTube at ARIN
#############################################
# WARNING  WARNING  WARNING  WARNING  WARNING
#############################################
#############################################
def get_ipv6_hostnames():
  for network in youtube_IPv6_addresses:
    ip_addresses = ipaddress.IPv6Network(network)
    for ip_address in ip_addresses:
      try:
         fully_qualified_domain_name = socket.getfqdn(str(ip_address))
         if fully_qualified_domain_name != str(ip_address):
          print (fully_qualified_domain_name)

      except Exception as error:
         print('The following error occurred: \n {}'.format(error))
```

Comment: Thanks it works without any SSLError, but I'm still stuck with **hostnames** problem. Using socket does not gives the result I expected.